# How do I create multiple file downloader without ActiveX?

Tags: java, javascript, html, apache-flex

I want to create multiple file downloader without Activex on web page.
please answer me how to do.

Comment: ...not to mention a rather unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing the files into a single zip file and offer to download that file.